# Splitting list into 4 even separate lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Currently I’m making a game. I want to evenly split all the players into 4 teams

```
teams = (List<List<Player>>)Lists.partition((List)players, Lists.partition((List)players, 4).size());
```

is what I tried so far (using classes from google guava). But that doesn’t work. What I’m trying to do is something like this:

Initial list:

```
[“jdjdb”,”jsid”,”hsisi”,”hri”,”idt”]
```

Output lists:

```
[[“jdjdb”, “jsid”],[“hsisi”],[“hri”], [“idt”]]
```

And it just adds the leftovers on to any of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something as follows:

```
final int size_split = 4;
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < size_split; i++)
    result.add(new ArrayList<>());

int count = 0;
for(String s : list){
    result.get(count % size_split).add(s);
    count++;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

First initialize the structure that will hold the four lists:

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < size_split; i++)
    result.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

Then iterate over the elements of the original list, and add them to the positions `0`, then `1`, then `2`, then `3` (and start over again) of the final list *i.e.,* round-robin fashion:

```
int count = 0;
for(String s : list){
    result.get(count % size_split).add(s);
    count++;
}
```

A Running example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("jdjdb");
        list.add("jsid");
        list.add("hsisi");
        list.add("hri");
        list.add("idt");

        final int size_split = 4;
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < size_split; i++)
            result.add(new ArrayList<>());

        int count = 0;
        for(String i : list){
            result.get(count % size_split).add(i);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[jdjdb, idt], [jsid], [hsisi], [hri]]
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple readable code is below hope it is what you asked for. . .let me know

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("e");
list.add("f");
list.add("g");
list.add("h");
list.add("i");
int size=list.size();
int sublistSize=size/4;
List<List<String>> teams=new ArrayList<List<String>>();
int lIndx=0;
int rIndx=0;
rIndx=sublistSize;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  List<String> subList=list.subList(lIndx,rIndx);
  lIndx=rIndx;
  if(i==2){
    rIndx=size;
  }else{
    rIndx+=sublistSize;
  }
  teams.add(subList);
}
```